# How to insert image behind blog post title

Tags: javascript, html, post, blogs, blogger

I need to how to insert image behind blog post title? I got some assistance from this  [site](http://creatingmyowncareer.com/blog-post-title/) but didn't work out.

```
</Group>

   <Group description="Post Title" selector="h3.post-title, h4, h3.post-title a">
     <Variable name="post.title.font" description="Font" type="font"
         default="normal bold 22px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif" value="normal bold 20px 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, sans-serif"/>
     <Variable name="post.title.text.color" description="Text Color" type="color" default="$(body.text.color)" value="#01689c"/>
   </Group>


    h3.post-title, h4 {
  font: $(post.title.font);
  color: $(post.title.text.color);
}

h3.post-title a {
  font: $(post.title.font);
  color: $(post.title.text.color);
}

h3.post-title a:hover {
  color: $(link.hover.color);
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
h3.post-title {
    background-image: url('Background_image_url_here');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked.... and do you how to how to make each posts to appear in each box?

Comment: Trying using `<span>` or `<div>`, and use CSS with it accordingly.